# rename a branch in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a change in Gerrit review in my current branch name called "foo".
I want to change the branch name to "bar", so I've used following command.

```
$ git branch -m bar
```

and then I did the git amend as I need the change of branch name appears to Gerrit review as well.

```
$ git commit --amend
```

However while doing git review, I'm getting following error.

```
$ git review bar
The branch 'bar' does not exist on the given remote 'gerrit'.
If these changes are intended to start a new branch, re-run with the
'-R' option enabled.
```

How can I rename the branch of change which is in Gerrit review?

I don't want to delete and create an another branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `bar` does not exist yet, you need to create it first. To create a branch, the account must be granted the access of [Create Reference](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#access_categories) on the reference `refs/heads/*`. If your account does not have the access, ask your Gerrit admin for help.

`bar` is supposed to be created from the parent commit of the current patchset of your change. You can find `parent` on the page of your current change.

After `bar` is created, you can cherry-pick the patchset onto `bar` on the change page. Or do it in the local repository:

```
# Checkout or reset to the patchset commit
git checkout <commit>

# Change the commit hash, as the original one has been pushed to refs/for/foo.
# Otherwise, it would fail to push the same commit to refs/for/bar.
git commit --amend --no-edit

# Push the new patchset to bar
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

After you rename the local branch, to rename the remote branch, you'll have to:

- Delete the old remote branch and push your new (renamed) local branch.

  `git push origin :old new`
- Reset the upstream branch for the new (renamed) local branch.

  Switch to the branch and run `git push origin -u new`

Where `old` refers to the old name branch and `new` refers to the renamed branch.

Comment: in step 2, when I do $ git push origin -u new, will it not push the changes as well to the remote branch? while the previous change is still in Gerrit for review? I don't want to push my other changes which are in Gerrit review, I just want to push the rename of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually mean to push a change for review targeting a new branch name, your local branch name is totally irrelevant. The target branch you push to is relevant. I'm not sure how you would do that using `git review` (as it hides/automates the target branch; e.g. `HEAD:refs/for/foo`).

---

What you could do is ***moving the review to another branch*** ([ssh command line, see `--move`](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.16.4/cmd-review.html) or [REST API / web interface](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.16.4/rest-api-changes.html#move-change)) - a feature available since 2.13:

[image]

---

For pushing manually, just push it to the new `refs/for/...` remote branch:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/bar
```

This assumes that your project settings allow to have the same Change-Id within the same project. See [project setting: `receive.createNewChangeForAllNotInTarget`](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html#receive.createNewChangeForAllNotInTarget). If your Gerrit remote does not accept the change, you may want to recreate the Change-Id (remove, amend, commit and your hook should take care of setting a new one). Then it would create a new change targeting the new remote branch.